# Invertibility of group Laplacian in $\ell^1$

Tags: gr.group-theory, fa.functional-analysis, geometric-group-theory, laplacian

Let $G$ be a discrete group and let $S$ be a generating set for $G$; assume that $S$ is symmetric (i.e., $g\in S$ iff $g^{-1}\in S$).  Let $L=L_S=\frac{1}{|S|}(\sum_{g\in S} g-1)$ be an element of the group algebra.  For $F\in \ell^p(G)$ and $g,h\in G$ let $\lambda_p(g) F$ be defined by $\lambda_p(g) F (h) = F(hg^{-1})$; this is the regular representation of $G$ on $\ell^p(G)$.  Finally let $L_p = \pi_p(L)$.

It is a classical result of Kesten that $G$ is non-amenable iff $L_2$ has a bounded inverse (i.e., $0$ is not in the spectrum of $L_2$).

What is known in the case of $p=1$? Clearly if $G$ is amenable, then there are functions $f_n\in \ell^1(G)$ with the property that $\Vert L_1 f_n \Vert_1 / \Vert f_n \Vert_1 \to 0$ showing that $0$ is in the spectrum of $L_1$ and so $L_1$ is not invertible.  Also, if $G$ is not amenable, then such $f_n$ cannot exist under the additional assumption that $f_n\geq 0$.

Given $G$ non-amenable, can one find a generating set $S$ with the property that $L_1$ is invertible?

Answer (score 4):

There is no generating set for which this is possible (actually this is true for any graph with an infinite connected component). Furthermore, your claim that (in non-amenable groups) such $f_n$ cannot exist if $f_n \geq 0$ is false. 
Here is a detailed proof.

**Lemma 1:** If $0 \leq v,w \in \ell^1G$ then $\|v+w\|_{\ell^1} = \|v \|_{\ell^1} + \|w\|_{\ell^1}$.

*Proof:* for all $g \in G$, $|v(g) + w(g)| = v(g) + w(g) = |v(g)| + |w(g)|$ this passes to the $\ell^1$-norm (by summing both sides over all $g$). $\hspace{10.5cm} \square$

**Lemma 2:** For any function $v \in \ell^1G$ and for any $g \in G$, $\|gv\|_{\ell^1} = \|v\|_{\ell^1}$. If further $v \geq 0$, $gv \geq 0$.

*Proof:* $gv$ has the same values as $v$ but permuted by the group action, so the norm is the same. The same reasoning shows that $Pv$ is positive when $v$ is. $\hspace{7.5cm} \square$

**Definition:** Let $P$ be the random walk operator: $P = \frac{1}{|S|} \sum_{g \in S} g$ or $P = L+I$ (where $I$ is the identity).

**Lemma 3:** for any $0 \leq v \in \ell^1G$, $\|Pv\|_{\ell^1} = \|v\|_{\ell^1}$ and $Pv \geq 0$.

*Proof:* Note that for any $g \in G$, $gv \geq 0$. $$
\begin{array}{rll}
\|Pv\|_{\ell^1} 
&= \| \tfrac{1}{|S|} \sum_{g \in S} gv \|_{\ell^1} 
& = \tfrac{1}{|S|} \| \sum_{g \in S} gv \|_{\ell^1}  \\
&\overset{Lemma 1}{=} 
\tfrac{1}{|S|}  \sum_{g \in S} \| gv \|_{\ell^1}  
&\overset{Lemma 2}{=} 
\tfrac{1}{|S|}  \sum_{g \in S} \| v \|_{\ell^1}  \\
&= \| v \|_{\ell^1} 
\end{array}
$$
$Pv$ is a strictly positive scalar times a sum of positive function, so it is positive. $\hspace{3cm} \square$

**Notation:** $P^k$ is $P$ applied $k$ times (e.g. $P^3 v= PPPv$) and $P^0 = I$.

**Lemma 4:** Let $f_n = \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n P^i v$ where $v \geq 0$ and $\|v\|_{\ell^1} =1$. 
Then $\|f_n\|_{\ell^1}= n+1$.

*Proof:* 
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
\|f_n\|_{\ell^1} 
&= \displaystyle \| \sum_{i=0}^n P^i v\|_{\ell^1}
& \overset{Lemma 1}{=} \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n  \| P^i v\|_{\ell^1}\\
& \overset{Lemma 3}{=} \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n  \|v\|_{\ell^1}
& = n+1. \\
\end{array}
$$

**Lemma 5:** Let $f_n = \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n P^i v$ where $v \geq 0$ and $\|v\|_{\ell^1} =1$. 
Then $\displaystyle \frac{\|L f_n\|_{\ell^1}}{\| f_n \|_{\ell^1}} \to 0$.

*Proof:* Let's compute $Lf_n$ using $L=P-I$:
$$
Lf_n = \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n LP^i v
= \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n (P-I)P^i v
= \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n \big( P^{i+1}v-P^i v \big)
= P^{n+1}v -v
$$
Now $\|Lf_n\|_{\ell^1} = \|P^{n+1}v -v\|_{\ell^1} \overset{TI}{\leq} \|P^{n+1}v\|_{\ell^1} + \|v\|_{\ell^1} = 2$ where $TI$ stands for the triangle inequality.

Using Lemma 4 $\displaystyle \frac{ \|L f_n\|_{\ell^1}}{\|f_n\|_{\ell^1}} \leq \frac{2}{n+1}$ which obviously tends to 0.

**Corollary:** 0 is in the spectrum of $L_1$ and the Laplacian cannot be inverted $\ell^1$.

Note the argument is true in any graph. If $v$ is supported on a finite component, then $\tfrac{1}{n+1} f_n$ tends to the constant function, which is indeed in the kernel. Otherwise $\tfrac{1}{n+1} f_n$ tends weak$^*$ to 0 but not in norm.

As a complementary remark **the image of the Laplacian** is not dense (in a graph with an infinite connected component).
By taking $v = \delta_x$, the Dirac mass at some vertex $x$, the sequence $f_n$ above shows its image is weak$^*$ dense.
It's easy to check that its image lies in $\ell^1_0X = \lbrace f \in \ell^1X \mid \sum_{x \in X} f(x) =0 \rbrace$. 
One can further check that $\overline{\mathrm{Im} \Delta} = \ell^1_0 X$ if and only if the graph has no non-constant bounded harmonic functions.
Non-amenable groups always have non-constant bounded harmonic functions so that the (norm) closure of the image of $\Delta$ is strict subspace of $\ell^1_0 X$.

Answer (score 2):

The Laplacian is never invertible on $\ell^1(G)$.

There is already a correct answer by ARG. 
I am writing this answer as there is a demand for more information. 
I will thus try to provide a more conceptual point of view. But I should remark that my answer is essentially the same as ARG's answer.

---

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $G$ and assume the Laplacian $\Delta=1-\mu$ is an automorphism of $\ell^1(G)$.
By taking the double dual, $\Delta$ extends to an automorphism of $\ell^\infty(G)^*$.
Recall that a mean on $G$ is a norm 1 positive element of $\ell^\infty(G)^*$ and let $M$ be the space of all means on $G$. It is easy to see that $M$ is convex and compact for the w*-topology. Note that $G$ acts on $M$ preserving its structure. In particular, $M$ is $\mu$-invariant. By [Markov–Kakutani fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem) there is a $\mu$-invariant mean $m\in M$. Thus $\ker \Delta\neq 0$ as 
$$ \Delta m=m-\mu m =0. $$
This is a contradiction.

---

Note that, by the same argument, $\Delta$ is never an automorphism of $\ell^\infty(G)$.
For completeness let me add that for $1<p<\infty$ and $\mu$ with a generating support, $\Delta$ is an automorphism of $\ell^p(G)$ iff $G$ is not amenable.
For this recall that the Mazur map $f \mapsto \text{sgn}(f)|f|^{2/p}$ is a $G$-equivariant uniformly continuous homeomorphism from the unit sphere of $\ell^2(G)$ to the unit sphere of $\ell^p(G)$. It follows that there exist almost invariant vectors in $\ell^p(G)$ iff there exist almost invariant vectors in $\ell^2(G)$, and this happens iff $G$ is amenable (by Kesten). Thus, if $G$ is amenable $\Delta$ is not an automorphism (and this works also for $p=1$). If $G$ is not amenable, by the uniform convexity of the unit ball of $\ell^p(G)$ (which fails for $p=1$), we get that $\|\mu\|<1$, thus the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu^n$ exists in the space of bounded operators, and since $(1-\mu)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu^n=1$, $\Delta$ is indeed an automorphism.

Comment: On a non-mathematical note: it appears that the OP is no longer active on this site

Comment: Indeed there was a bounty added by the person who wrote the other answer, who didn't specify its purpose. Anyway this additional answer is very welcome (and possibly the OP is still active under another nickname).

Comment: Uri, a small question since I am being slow: in the last part, when dealing with $\ell^p$, is the point that the Mazur map also intertwines the G-action?

Comment: Oh... I didn't realize that the bounty was suggested by ARG. I thought it was offered by the OP. I was indeed surprised, as ARG's answer is perfect.

Comment: @Yemon Thanks for asking. Indeed, I was very brief at this part. Yes, the point is that the Mazur map intertwines the action. It follows that the existence of almost invariant vectors is a phenomena independent of $1\leq p <\infty$. This statement was recorded as Remark 4.3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506361.pdf, and further explanation could be found there. But the thing I wanted to emphasize here, is that not having almost invariants does not automatically imply invertability. It does, under further uniform convexity assumption, which is what fails for $p=1$.

Comment: Sorry for the clumsy bounty, I was seriously thinking my answer was wrong (because it did not get any upvotes, while the question did [in the same time span]) and I was trying to get the attention of the OP (which seems to be futile if I understandYemon's comment). In any case, Uri's answer is very nice, so I'll be glad to give him the "bounty".

Comment: By the way, another method to do the $\ell^p$ case is as follows (it can be found in a very short paper of Lohoue). Check that the operator norm of $P$ is $\leq 1$ for $\ell^\infty \to \ell^\infty$ and for $\ell^1 \to \ell^1$. Now a group is amenable iff $\|P\|_{\ell^2 \to \ell^2} < 1$. By the Riesz-Thorin interpolation, $\|P\|_{\ell^p \to \ell^p} \leq \|P\|_{\ell^2 \to \ell^2}^r \|P\|_{\ell^1 \to \ell^1}^s$ or $\|P\|_{\ell^p \to \ell^p} \leq \|P\|_{\ell^2 \to \ell^2}^r \|P\|_{\ell^\infty \to \ell^\infty}^s$ ($r$ and $s$ depend on $p$, as well as the bound by $\ell^1$ or $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: The same interpolation argument can be used to show $\|P\|_{\ell^2\to \ell^2} < 1$ if $\|P\|_{\ell^p \to \ell^p} <1$ (as long as $1<p<\infty$). This was partly a motivation for my question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217775/lp-norm-estimates-for-the-inverse-of-the-laplacian-on-a-graph

Comment: @ARG, so essentially you say that you put a bounty to encourage people to proofread your answer and check correctness? I am doing such things anonymously for some years with never getting any bounty...

Comment: Let me also add that, by my personal experience, I am not expecting people to upvote good answers. It does happen some time, but usually a good question with a simple good answer are just being ignored by most of us. This is compatible with Cunningham's Law, see https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law. I have more to say here, but probably this is not the right forum.

Comment: @Uri well, it's not because you usually don't get a "reward" that you should not... Thanks for pointing out Cunningham's Law, it does puts things in perspective!